# How do I setup 2 different instances of WooCommerce on "one" website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm performing some work for my company - and am shackled by Wordpress, TheGEM theme, and WooCommerce (also B2B for WooCommerce Plugin) but that isn't an immediate issue.

the company ALSO wants to use WooCommerce as a Catalog as well - but i'm struggling to figure out how to have it set up as a Catalog on one page while still functioning as a store in the normal WooCommerce areas.

Can anyone suggest anything that may help with this? is my best option to set up a subdomain and have a completely seperate instance running there?

thanks,

i've tried to create different templates, set up different attributes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your requirement properly but I think you want to show the same thing differently for the catalog page and also the store page.

1. First Leave the shore as it is.
2. Use a custom meta box for any additional info for the catalog.
3. Do custom queries to show things differently on a Catalog page.
4. If you want to show things differently you also can load a different template for the catalog view using a new query string at the end of the product URL.

Here is an example: This is one of my product URL
https://wpmania.net/Store/product/environmental-services-wordpress-theme/

And here is the same URL with a new query string https://wpmania.net/Store/product/environmental-services-wordpress-theme/live-demo

Here is the code example...

```html
// adding custom query string
add_action('init', 'product_add_endpoints');
function product_add_endpoints()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint('live-demo', EP_PERMALINK);
}

add_filter('request', 'product_filter_request');
function product_filter_request($vars)
{
    if (isset($vars['live-demo'])) $vars['live-demo'] = true;
    return $vars;
}
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/

You just need to be creative about what you want.
Hope this helps.